# Symfony2: How to display choices field text?

Tags: php, symfony

I generate a doctrine CRUD files first.
This form has a choice field that has choices value and names.
newAction and updateAction uses this.
But index(list)Action display a raw value, not name.
How to best way to display choices name in index.html.twig?

SampleFormType.php

```
$builder->add('name')
    ->add('isActive', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(false => 'Inactive', true => 'Active'),
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
    ));
```

index.html.twig

```
{% for entity in entities %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ entity.isActive }}</td>
    <!-- Show '0' or '1', not 'Inactive' or 'Active' -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Shoud i make filter of twig extension or convert value to name in controller?

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this. A simple one is a basic conditional

```
{{ entity.isActive ? 'Active' : 'Inactive' }}
```

But this could very quickly violate [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) if you need to use this value in more than one place.

I think twig extensions should be reserved for things that aren't so domain specific. You could use [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html), but those usually serve another purpose as well.

The more architecturally sound idea is to not send Entity objects to the view at all. In a system of good MVC separation, the **View** and the **Model** don't interact directly.

Consider how Symfony already handles views for complex objects like [forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form) - you can adopt a similar pattern for your entities. You could even consider using something like [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/), which was designed for hypermedia APIs but could definitely be used for view objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know macros. I will try this.